# Proving $S^1$, the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, is path-connected

Tags: proof-explanation, path-connected

I am trying to prove that $S^1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ is path connected, so I need to, for any $(a,b), (c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, find a function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that is continuous, that $f(t) \in S^1$ for all $t$, and $f(0) = (a,b)$, $f(1) = (c,d)$.

I can't figure out how to get started. The function should be a straight line of some sort joining the points, but that doesn't lie entirely on the boundary of the circle. I could take an arc, which surely would lie on the circle, but I don't know how to write out its equation. Polar coordinates is the first thing that comes to mind.

Any help on the formalization would be appreciated.

Comment: Yep, an arc will work fine, and so "the equation" is essentially asking how do you parametrize an arc.  Polar coordinates work fine, as you suspect.

Comment: The function need not be a straight line. It has to be  a continuous function *from* the "straight line" (segment) $[0,1]$ to $S^1$, but there is no reason its image has to be a straight line. Paths need not be lines.

Comment: The notion of parametrizing an arc makes sense to me; though I know how to use polar coordinates, I can't think of a formal way to say it other than picking two points, specifying their two polar angles, and then saying "take every angle in between, fixing $r=1$." Is there a better way to say it?

Answer (score 5):

Using polar coordinates, we can write $S^1=\{(\cos \theta,\sin\theta):\theta \in [0,2\pi]\}$. Thus we can define a map $f:[0,2\pi] \rightarrow S^1$ by $\theta \mapsto (\cos \theta,\sin\theta)$. This map is continuous surjective. Hence $S^1$ is the continuous image of an interval, which is path-connected.

Comment: I appreciate this very helpful result, though I don't have the notion of connectedness yet or this result, so I'm trying to define a path directly.

Comment: A path is just a continuous image of a closed interval. The map $f$ is already a path.

Answer (score 2):

Although i go with the above answer, I am writing this with a guess that this is what you are looking for:

Let us write the points on the circle in polar coordinates. Let $ z_1= e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z_2 = e^{i\theta_2}$ be two points. Without loss of generality assume that $\theta_1<\theta_2$. Hence $0 \leq \theta_1 < \theta_2 \leq  2\pi$ (I am assuming that $\theta_1 \neq \theta_2$.

You can deal it in two ways:

1. Define explicitly a map $f$ from $[0,1]$ as follows:
   $$f(t) = e^{i\left(\theta_2t+(1-t)\theta_1\right)}$$.
   This is a continuous map (as it is a composition of two continuous functions). Image lies on unit circle. And the initial and final points are $z_1$ and $z_2$ respectively.
2. You may define a map $f$ from $[\theta_1, \theta_2]$, as
   $$f(t)= e^{it}.$$
   $f(t)$ lies on unit circle and the initial and final points are $z_1$ and $z_2$ respectively. Since you can define a continuous Map $g$ from $[0_1]$ to $[\theta_1, \theta 2]$, consider $f$ composition $g$. You will be done.

A path need not always be from $[0,1]$. Since any two closed intervals are equivalent, a path may be from any closed interval interval $[a,b]$.